# LibGdx data persistance with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm still new in LibGdx and also Android programming..

I'm trying to create a class that will be used to store data in my application 
the class looks like this

```
package com.mygdx.hanoi.util;

import java.util.Map;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;

public class DataPersister2 {

    public Preferences getOrCreatePreferences(String prefName){
        return Gdx.app.getPreferences(prefName + ".prefs");
    }
    public Map getPreferencesData(Preferences prefName){
        return (Map) prefName.get(); //.get(key);
    }
    public void clearPreferences(Preferences prefName){
        prefName.clear();
    }
    public void insertPreferences(Preferences prefName, Map data){
        prefName.put(data);
        prefName.flush();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i try to create a preferences using that class, and adding an ArrayList into it, it always said that the preferences is null

```
DataPersister2 hs = new DataPersister2();
        Preferences hScore = hs.getOrCreatePreferences("highScores");
        hs.clearPreferences(hScore);

        // dummy test score data
        ArrayList<String[]> hsFreeMode = new ArrayList<String[]>();  // declare apa yang mau ditaruh sini, biar ga error di kemudian method
        hsFreeMode.add(new String[] {"luki", "5000"});
        hsFreeMode.add(new String[] {"laras", "3900"});

        ArrayList hsMoveMode = new ArrayList();
        hsMoveMode.add(new String[] {"cika", "6000"});
        hsMoveMode.add(new String[] {"cikoo", "1000"});

        Map hsMap = new HashMap();
        hsMap.put("freeMode", hsFreeMode);
        hsMap.put("moveMode", hsMoveMode);

        //hs.insertPreferences("highScores", hsMap);
        hs.insertPreferences(hScore, hsMap);

        // print out the data
        Map data = hs.getPreferencesData(hScore);
        Gdx.app.log("data print", "the free mode value is " + (String[]) data.get("freeMode"));
        Gdx.app.log("Array List", "the arraylist contains" + hsFreeMode.get(0)[0]);
```

Whenever i try to log from that class (in 'data print' log) it always says null
But if i log it directly from the ArrayList (in 'Array List' log) the value appears..

what makes it even more strange for me is, if i change the map value before adding it to the preferences like this :

```
Map hsMap = new HashMap();
    hsMap.put("freeMode", "luki");
    hsMap.put("moveMode", "laras");

    //hs.insertPreferences("highScores", hsMap);
    hs.insertPreferences(hScore, hsMap);
```

and log the data like this :

```
Gdx.app.log("data print", "the free mode value is " + data.get("freeMode"));
```

the data shown...
so i'm confused right now, and can't figure out (yet) where is my problem..

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to libgdx documentation [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) support only **String** and **primitive types** so you cannot just put array into preferences. You need to serialize it before putting and deserialize after getting data using for example [JSON](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.html)

```
    //adding to the preferences:

    hsMap.put("freeMode", json.toJson( hsFreeMode ) );


    //and then:

    Gdx.app.log("data print", "the free mode value is " + ( (String[])json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, String[].class, (String)data.get("freeMode") ).get(0) )[0] );
```